# For a finite structure $\mathfrak A$ in an *infinite* language, is $Th \mathfrak A$ decidable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

In Enderton's logic, Theorems 26C and 26D, the assumption is that the first order language is finite.

Theorem 26C: For a finite structure $\mathfrak A$ in a finite language, $Th \mathfrak A$ is decidable.

Theorem 26D: For a finite language, $\{\sigma | \sigma \text{ has a finite model} \}$ is effectively enumerable.

Is a finite language a necessary assumption in these two theorems? So long as the universe of some structure is finite, one could build a tree from the finite sentence $\sigma$ and evaluate all the leaves with the values from the universe.

If a sentence of the form $\forall c \phi(c)$, where c referred to constants is allowed, then a finite language would be a necessary assumption. But I believe that $\forall$ can only range over variables.

Comment: I think it is important that you clarify whether $\sigma$ is a single sentence or a (possibly infinite) set of sentences. 26D is false on the latter reading.

Comment: @RobArthan 26D is *meaningless* on the latter meaning; what does it mean to say that a collection of possibly infinite sets is c.e.? This doesn't need clarification.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  I just read "$\sigma$ has a finite model" with no constraint on whether $\sigma$ is a single sentence or a set of sentences.  The idea of collection of sets whose characteristic functions are encoded by an r.e. set of encodings of recursive functions sounds like a reasonable thing to me. I thought the question would be improved by a minor clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note that in order to make sense of computability-flavored questions around infinite languages, we need to think of symbols as being represented by natural numbers in some reasonable way. This is something we can ignore when the language is finite, but with infinite languages it's important.*

---

Theorem $26D$ makes no *real* use of the finiteness of the language. This is because every sentence can only use finitely many symbols. Really the only way complexity can enter the picture is if the language we're looking at is itself of high complexity, in which case the set of sentences in that language itself *(not even thinking about the set of sentences in that language with finite models, yet)* will be of high complexity. But this has nothing to do with the finite model property. A bit more precisely, as long as $\Sigma$ is a computable language, the set of $\Sigma$-sentences which have finite models is c.e. - given a computable language $\Sigma$ and a $\Sigma$-sentence $\sigma$, let $\Sigma_0$ be the finite fragment of $\Sigma$ which actually appears in $\sigma$ and search through the finite $\Sigma_0$-structures for one satisfying $\sigma$.

---

Theorem $26C$, by contrast, absolutely does rely on a finite language. Take for example a language with a unary relation symbol $U_i$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ (note that this language is computable!). For each set $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, let $\mathfrak{M}_X$ be the structure whose universe consists of a single element, such that $U_i$ holds on that element iff $i\in X$. Then $Th(\mathfrak{M}_X)$ computes $X$ since we have $$i\in X\iff\mathfrak{M}_X\models\exists xU_i(x).$$ So now just pick some really complicated $X$.

Informally speaking, the infinite language lets us "access" each of the bits of $X$ (using one symbol per bit), and so code the entire complexity of $X$ into the theory of the resulting structure. If we tried to do this with only finitely many $U_i$s, we'd only get finitely much information about $X$, which - regardless of how complicated $X$ is - would be computable. And the fact that every finite structure in a finite language has a computable theory demonstrates that there's no clever way around this.

Comment: Is X the universe for the structure M? Is X not computable? But if the universe is not computable, then even in a finite language, Th(M_x) is not decidable.

Comment: @Travis08 No, the universe for $M$ just has a single element - say, its universe is $\{17\}$, if you care specifically (as I say, "the structure with a single element"). The universe is **very** computable! The point is that all the complexity of $X$ gets folded into how the $U_i$s are interpreted; the fact that $\mathfrak{M}_X$ has only one element doesn't limit this. In a finite language this sort of coding wouldn't be possible, but once we have an infinite language we can do things like this.

Comment: So the universe for M is computable. But X is not computable, correct? Suppose I have a structure M and the universe has a single element 0. The structure uses a finite language with one unary relation symbol U.  U is defined in the following way: $0 \in U$ iff $0 \in X$. Since X is not computable (there's no way to compute whether 0 is in X or not), a sentence involving U is not decidable.

Comment: @Travis08 No, that's not right - any finite amount of information is computable. Regardless of how complicated $X$ is, the answer to the question "Is $0\in X$?" - and so any structure depending entirely on the answer to this question, in the way you've described! - will be very simple. We need a unary relation for *each* "bit" of $X$, which is why the language has to be infinite.

Comment: @Travis08 I've edited to clarify this.

Comment: "Any finite amount of information is computable." Based on your answer to my previous question, I assume that $0 \in U$ iff $0 \in X$ is decidable. Am I correct? If so, then $U_1(x)$ is decidable, $U_2(x)$ is decidable, etc. In an infinite language, any sentence $\sigma$ from the language is going to include only a finite number of $U_i$. Each of the $U_i$ in $\sigma$ is decidable. Thus the entire sentence $\sigma$ is decidable.

Comment: @Travis08 I'm not sure what you mean by "$0\in U$ iff $0\in X$" - there is *no* "$U$" at all. There is a separate $U_i$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$. I also don't know what you mean by "the entire sentence $\sigma$ is decidable" - it doesn't really make sense to talk about a *single* sentence being decidable or undecidable in this context, for the same reason. What is true is that for each $n$ the theory of $\mathfrak{M}_X$ restricted to formulas using only the symbols $U_k$ for $k<n$ is computable - but this isn't **uniform in $n$** so this doesn't give the computability of $Th(\mathfrak{M}_X)$.

Comment: I was wrong to speak about a sentence $\sigma$ as decidable. I meant it is possible to decide for any single sentence $\sigma$ whether $\sigma$ is a member of Th(M_x). Because it seems that you are saying that for every fixed $U_i$, it is possible to decide whether $i \in X$. What does it mean to say, "isn't uniform in n"? Do you have an example of an X? Something concrete might help me understand. (I couldn't move this conversation to chat. If this conversation has grown too tedious for you, that's fine. My understanding this answer may be outside of my current knowledge base.)

Comment: @Travis08: I think you should go back to the definition of decidability of the theory. It basically means that there is a*fixed*  procedure which, given an *arbitrary* sentence, tells you whether that sentence follows from the theory or not (in finitely many steps). Since you can code any set as the set of true sentences in a theory of a singleton structure (in an infinite language), including sets which are not recursive, singleton structures are not decidable.

Comment: @tomasz My difficulty is understanding "Any finite amount of information is computable." Suppose $X \subseteq \mathbb N$ is the range of the Busy Beaver function. Suppose there is a structure $\mathfrak M_x$ with a finite number of $U_i$ (from 1 to $10^{{10}^{10}})$, where each $U_i$ is satisfied by the single element 0 from the universe iff $i$ is a member of the range of the Busy Beaver function. $Th(\mathfrak M_x)$ is decidable according to the theorem. What does "decidable" in this context mean, since we can't prove using ZFC what the BB number is for 748 states?

Comment: @Travis08: It doesn't matter whether or not we know or can know what the number is. It is enough that we know that the number exists (otherwise, the structure would not be well defined). So (for simplicity, only for formulas $(\exists x)U_i(x)$), to define the procedure, take $X_0=X\cap [0, 10^{10^{10}}]$. Then, the procedure is as follows: if $i\in X_0$, return True, else return False. Since $X_0$ is finite, all is fine --- the decision procedure exists. Not knowing $X_0$, we don't know what it is, we *can't* know what it is, but we *know* it exists --- so we have decidability.

Comment: In other words, decidability is *not* a constructive statement, but merely an existential one.

Comment: @tomasz Here's my 'decision procedure' that uses your example as a template to determine whether a sentence $\sigma$ is satisfied by a structure $\mathfrak M_x$ with an infinite language. The structure uses the Busy Beaver function to determine whether the unary predicates are satisfied or not (as above).

Comment: Let $X$ be the range of BB. Let $\sigma$ be a sentence from the language. $\sigma$ is finite and has a finite number of prime formulas. For simplicity, let's assume they are all of the form $\exists(x)U_i(x)$. Let k = Maximum $i$ of the $U_i$ in $\sigma$ -- since the number of $U_i$ in $\sigma$ is finite, that is possible. Let $X_0 = X \cap [0, k]$. Then the decision procedure is as follows: if $i \in X_0$ return True, else return False. Since $X_0$ is finite, all is fine --- the decision procedure exists.

Comment: @Travis08 That doesn't work because your "algorithm" needs to work *for all $k$*. This means that while each *instance of* the algorithm only needs finitely much information to be "baked in," the *algorithm as a whole* uses the full complexity of $X$. This is exactly what I was getting at re: **uniformity** above, and tomasz is absolutely right. Since this has nothing to do with the original model theory question, and this comment thread is getting long, I suggest asking a separate question about this if you're still confused.

Comment: @Travis08: Noah already explained this nicely, but putting it differently: what you have described (well, approximately) is a procedure to decide whether or not a *fixed* $\sigma$ is satisfied in the structure. There is no place for input (which was $i$ in my example). So the procedure can be even simpler than what you describe: if $\sigma$ is satisfied, return True, else return False. But this only works for this one $\sigma$, so that tells you nothing about decidability.